# Filter arrays of Object inside an Object in JS

Tags: javascript

I have the following Object.

```
"events": {
  "foo": [
    {
      "end": "1/2/2019"
    },
    {
      "end": "2/12/2019"
    }
  ],
  "bar": [
    {
      "end": "1/2/2019"
    },
    {
      "end": "2/12/2019"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to filter the events based on the end date and create something like below:

```
"events": {
  "foo": [
    {
      "end": "2/12/2019"
    }
  ],
  "bar": [
    {
      "end": "2/12/2019"
    }
  ]
}
```

OR

```
"events": [
  {
    "end": "2/12/2019"
  },
  {
    "end": "2/12/2019"
  }
]
```

I was wondering how can I do this using ES2015 method.

I tried the following:

```
return Object.values(this.events).map(a=>{
 a.filter(b=>{
   new Date(b.end) > new Date()
 })
})
```

But it's all returning undefined arrays.

Comment: Your assumption about comparing dates is incorrect - you should compare with a value from the date, such as `(new Date()).getTime()`

Comment: Try looking at .reduce() method of Arrays.

Comment: @chazsolo the date part is working fine. I checked it separately.

Comment: Remove the `{}` from `map` and `filter`, they're not being returned.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing return statements in the above code. Your code should look something like this -

```js
return Object.values(this.events).map(a => {
    return a.filter(b => {
        return new Date(b.end) > new Date()
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's useful to break a problem like this down into its constituent parts.  You want to filter the results of each of the array properties (`foo` and `bar`) of your `events` object to only include those whose `end` property matches some condition.  (You don't specify, so I'm assuming that the condition might be "after 1/31/2019".)

Well we can easily write a function that tells if the `end` property comes after a given date.  And we know how to filter arrays, although here I include a convenience function to make it easier.  So then we need a way to map our function over an object, the way `Array.prototype.map` maps over an array.  Here I write a simple `mapObject` to do this.

Combining them into `filterByDateAfter` gives us a function we can call like this:

```js
filterByDateAfter ('1/31/2019') (events)
```

to get the result you're after.

```js
const mapObject = (fn) => (obj) => 
  Object .entries (obj)
    .reduce ((a, [k, v]) => ({...a, [k]: fn(v)}), {})

const filter = (pred) => (arr) => 
  arr .filter (pred)

const endAfter = (str, d = new Date (str)) => (obj) =>
  new Date (obj .end) > d

const filterByDateAfter = (dateStr) => mapObject (filter (endAfter (dateStr) ) )

const events = {"bar": [{"end": "1/2/2019"}, {"end": "2/12/2019"}], "foo": [{"end": "1/2/2019"}, {"end": "2/12/2019"}]}

console .log (
  filterByDateAfter ('1/31/2019') (events)
)
```

The point here is that we've broken your problem down into tiny pieces.  Two of them, `mapObject` and `filter`, are quite reusable, and the others are extremely simple.